# mapView layout with LinearLayout fails?

Tags: android

I want to have a mapView and above it a thin strip of buttons.
But when I put in a LinearLayout, the map will not render. No errors, just no rendering.
Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/h1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <CheckBox 
         android:text="Satellite" 
         android:id="@+id/satellite" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </CheckBox>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/uoicon" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:apiKey="0zDdYFYf6Ir2W-NuiHPLAoFjsq0nmqRhPfzjY3A"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

If I take out the inner LinearLayout everything works fine, although my thin strip of buttons
(in this case just a checkbox and image) are a column.

Anyone have any answers as to why this would prevent mapView from rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the inner layout to use `wrap_content` for the height.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks much.  Simply criminal, though, that such a simple layout change can cause the entire mapview to fail.